# Does initContext return the same resource in Tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, connection-pooling

I am trying to setup db connection pooling in Tomcat. But I'm not sure that I understand the context container.

In my context xml I have:

```
  <Resource name="jdbc/connName" auth="Container" type="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource"
           maxActive="20" maxIdle="10" maxWait="100"
           user="user" password="pass" driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
           url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:db"
           factory="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSourceFactory"
           />
```

Then when I need to use the DB I get a connection like this:

```
    Context initContext;
    Context envContext;
    OracleDataSource ds;
    try {
        initContext = new InitialContext();
        envContext = (Context) initContext.lookup("java:/comp/env/jdbc");
        ds = (OracleDataSource) envContext.lookup("connName");
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        LOG.error(e, e);
        throw new InternalDatabaseException("Could not get pooled DB connection");  
    }

    if (envContext == null) throw new InternalDatabaseException("Error: No Context");
    if (ds == null) throw new InternalDatabaseException("Error: No DataSource");
    if (ds != null) dbConn = ds.getConnection();
    if (dbConn == null) throw new InternalDatabaseException("Error: No Connection");
```

Now what appears to be happening is that instead of getting the same pool every where I call that code, I am creating a new pool. Is this correct?

The reason I think I am getting a new pool is that I am getting over 300 connections to the DB.

Comment: Tomcat should create the pool once in JNDI, and then your code would look that same pool up each time. What makes you think it's creating a new pool each time?

Comment: I had multiple connections left open. They were left open as I was not closing the handles correctly. But the reason I thought I was getting multiple pools was the number of connections. Over 300 was far more than the 100 max, set in the context.xml.